# SwiftUI multiple popovers in a List

Tags: swiftui, popover

I defined 2 popovers and one sheet in the View `Line()`.
Using this view in a VStack, everything works fine.
Using it inside a List, the wrong popovers /sheets are displayed when the corresponding text or Button is tapped.
What's going wrong here?

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Line()
      List {
        Line()
        Line()
        Line()
      }
    }
  }
}

struct Line: View {
  @State private var showPopup1 = false
  @State private var showPopup2 = false
  @State private var showSheet2 = false

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("popover 1")
      .onTapGesture { self.showPopup1 = true}
      .popover(isPresented: $showPopup1, arrowEdge: .trailing )
      { Popover1(showSheet: self.$showPopup1) }
      .background(Color.red)

      Text("popover 2")
      .onTapGesture { self.showPopup2 = true }
      .popover(isPresented: $showPopup2, arrowEdge: .trailing )
      { Popover2(showSheet: self.$showPopup2) }
      .background(Color.yellow)

      Button("Sheet2"){self.showSheet2 = true}
      .sheet(isPresented: self.$showSheet2, content: { Sheet2()})
    }
  }
}

struct Popover1: View {
  @Binding var showSheet: Bool

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("Poppver 1 \(self.showSheet ? "T" : "F")")
      Button("Cancel"){ self.showSheet = false }
    }
  }
}

struct Popover2: View {
  @Binding var showSheet: Bool

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("Poppver 2")
      Button("Cancel"){ self.showSheet = false }
    }
  }
}

struct Sheet2: View {
  @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentation

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("Sheet 2")
      Button("Cancel"){ self.presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss() }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: may i see Popover1 and Popover2 code?

Comment: @user3441734  Popover1 and Popover2 code is in the post#

Comment: yes i see now ...

Comment: 1) remove all but one Line() 2) select "show animation" from simulator debug menu. 3) try it :-). the reason will be clear soon. yes, I know, you will be not very happy, but the only solution is don't use any "extra" gesture in List row, till ListStyle will not be available for developers.  sorry ...

Comment: i didn't mention, use swipe down to dismiss ... to see the reason

Comment: thx, I tried it, but I still don't understand the reason ;-(.  If I interpret your last sentence correctly, there is no way to have multiple gestures in List-Fields at the moment.

Comment: yes, at least it is not simple solution. and see, that while swipe down, you can see other modal appears for a while. unfortunately, there is almost no chance to debug that, because you don't have access to List internals. I use ScrollView indeed ... even though there is a lot of thinks to implement.

Comment: I made some experiments with scrollview, but it was horribly slow with 1000 Items in the scrollview. Is there an approach to increase the performance. I think List makes some things like reusing cells.

Comment: in general, (not swiftui specific) it is a good idea to use some kind of "pagination". There is only few rows on the screen, i try to limit my "reusable" cells to few only. most likely that is how List works too.

Answer (score 2):

Just don't use `Button` for `.sheet`. `List` detects buttons in row and activate entire row (not sure about bug, let it be *as designed*). So using only and for everywhere in sub-elements gestures, makes your code work.

Tested with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2

```swift
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("popover 1")
        .onTapGesture { self.showPopup1 = true}
      .popover(isPresented: $showPopup1, arrowEdge: .trailing )
      { Popover1(showSheet: self.$showPopup1) }
      .background(Color.red)

      Text("popover 2")
      .onTapGesture { self.showPopup2 = true }
      .popover(isPresented: $showPopup2, arrowEdge: .trailing )
      { Popover2(showSheet: self.$showPopup2) }
      .background(Color.yellow)

      Text("Sheet2")                             // << here !!!
      .onTapGesture {self.showSheet2 = true}     // << here !!!
      .sheet(isPresented: self.$showSheet2, content: { Sheet2()})
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thnx, but does not work. In some cases still the wrong popover appears. If it would work, wouldn't this cause a performance issue, if you have a List with e.g. 5000 items?